# Sencha Touch: onUpdated() function + Ext.MessageBox pop-ups freeze my Sencha app

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

1. Am building a Sencha Touch app. Each time I build a new app version and the function below is called
   my app freezes on all web browsers, iOS device and Android device. I cannot press anything after the Ext.Message.Box
   is show whether i want to update the app.

onUpdated: function() {
                Ext.Msg.confirm(
                        "Application Update",
                        "This application has been updated to a new version. Reload now?",
                        function(buttonId) {
                            if (buttonId === 'yes') {
                                window.location.reload();
                            }
                        }
                    );
                },

1. Whenever an Ext.MessageBox opens it freezes my app, when I click on any of the options (No Ok), nothing happens.
   The app is basically frozen.

I have added in requires: ['Ext.MessageBox'] in app.js
I have read multiple online pages on it, but to no avail
Does somebody have experience with these 2 errors? They seem to be related.

Comment: 2 years and still this bug...grrrr..